# Wordpress Target Blank

Tags: hyperlink

I'm working a [wordpress theme versatile](http://themes.goodlayers2.com/?theme=versatile) and I have a price table that has "Order Now" button but the button does not link in a new tab and I want to change that.

I'm not to familiar with php but I know I will have to place a **target=“_blank”** code in the php file but I'm not sure where.

Does anyone know where I can place this little bugger at? 
Thanks in advance.

```
// price table item
if( !function_exists('gdlr_get_price_table_item') ){
    function gdlr_get_price_table_item( $settings ){
        $item_id = empty($settings['page-item-id'])? '': ' id="' . $settings['page-item-id'] . '" ';

        global $gdlr_spaces;
        $margin = (!empty($settings['margin-bottom']) && 
            $settings['margin-bottom'] != $gdlr_spaces['bottom-item'])? 'margin-bottom: ' . $settings['margin-bottom'] . ';': '';
        $margin_style = (!empty($margin))? ' style="' . $margin . '" ': '';         

        $settings['price-table'] = empty($settings['price-table'])? array(): $settings['price-table'];
        $list = is_array($settings['price-table'])? $settings['price-table']: json_decode($settings['price-table'], true);
        $ret  = '<div class="gdlr-item gdlr-price-table-item" ' . $item_id . $margin_style . '>';
        foreach( $list as $tab ){ 
            $best_price = ($tab['gdl-tab-active'] == 'yes')? ' best-price ': '';

            $ret .= '<div class="gdlr-price-item ' . gdlr_get_column_class('1/' . $settings['columns']) . '">';
            $ret .= '<div class="gdlr-price-inner-item ' . $best_price . '">';

            $ret .= '<div class="price-title-wrapper">';
            $ret .= '<h4 class="price-title">' . gdlr_text_filter($tab['gdl-tab-title']) . '</h4>';
            $ret .= '<div class="price-tag">' . gdlr_text_filter($tab['gdl-tab-price']) . '</div>';
            $ret .= '</div>';

            $ret .= '<div class="price-content">' . gdlr_content_filter($tab['gdl-tab-content']) . '</div>';

            if(!empty($tab['gdl-tab-link'])){
                $ret .= '<div class="price-button">';
                $ret .= '<a class="gdlr-button without-border" href="' . esc_url($tab['gdl-tab-link']) . '">' . __('Order Now', 'gdlr_translate') . '</a>';
                $ret .= '</div>';
            }

            $ret .= '</div>'; // gdlr-price-inner-item
            $ret .= '</div>'; // gdlr-price-item
        }
        $ret .= '<div class="clear"></div>';
        $ret .= '</div>';

        return $ret;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its gonna be in this line:

`$ret .= '<a class="gdlr-button without-border" href="' . esc_url($tab['gdl-tab-link']) . '">' . __('Order Now', 'gdlr_translate') . '</a>';`

Should be changed to:

`$ret .= '<a class="gdlr-button without-border" href="' . esc_url($tab['gdl-tab-link']) . '">' . __('Order Now', 'gdlr_translate') . 'target="_blank" </a>';`

Comment: apparently that code didn't work. Not sure why but here is the link
http://www.churchsentinel.com/background-direct/

Comment: I assume you are working on [this page](http://www.churchsentinel.com/background-direct/)? If so, the look at the buttons. If you inspect element on those buttons on that page, the printed link will be this ```<a class="gdlr-button without-border" href="https://signup.backgrounddirect.com/pub/app.jsp?moduleName=2">Order now</a>``` Notice the class of ```gdlr-button without-border```? Now notice the 'Order Now' text and same class of ```gdlr-button without-border``` in my code above? That means your ```target=_blank``` has to go there. There isn't another fit anywhere on the page.